# Supervised learning in non-stationary environments?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, stationarity, transfer-learning

For real applications, concept drifts often exist, i.e., the relationship between the input and output changes overtime. I'm wondering what are the most common methods to enable neural networks to quickly adapt to the changing environment for supervised learning? For example, the relationship between vital measurements of patients and their risk may change over time. Say, we have two patients A and B with the exactly same measurements. We encountered A in 2000, and B in 2010. It turns our that A is risky but B is not. Ideally, we want our system to quickly adapt to such change in the relationship.

I'm aware of some simply methods such as fine-tuning, training from scratch from the current data. Is there any other more sophisticated methods that can better model the changing dynamics of the environment?

Thanks!